# Create a task sequence in Cakebuild

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I am using Cake 0.23.0 and was happy to read that task dependencies have been extended. Unfortunately it seems even the latest version does not solve my problem. **Or am I just doing something wrong?**

**What I would like to achieve**

- Supposing I have tasks defined that are equal for multiple platforms (e.g. x86 or x64)
- I would like to define a build sequence that is first doing all tasks for platform x86. Once done an init task should be executed that is just setting the platform to x64 and then the same tasks should be executed as for x86.
- Example sequence:
  Task Init x86 -> Task A -> Task B -> Task C -> Task Init x64 -> Task A -> Task B -> Task C

**Current Behaviour**
The resulting sequence is
Task Init x86 -> Task A -> Task B -> Task C -> Task Init x64

It seems Cake does only respect task dependency once. I have defined it like shown below:

```
Task("Compile-All-Platforms")
  .IsDependentOn("Init-86")  
  .IsDependentOn("A")
  .IsDependentOn("B")
  .IsDependentOn("C")
  .IsDependentOn("Init-x64")
  .IsDependentOn("A")
  .IsDependentOn("B")
  .IsDependentOn("C");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build in two large steps, the naive way to do it would be encapsulate the build logic of A, B and C in helper functions and then wrap them in x86 or x64 tasks. The idea here is to leverage the dependency tree Cake is able to create for you instead of writing down all the dependencies in Compile-All. Actually, this is the main reason why you want to use build orchestrators.

Granted, this is a straightforward way to make it work for 3 tasks and 2 platforms. A much more scalable solution would be to create and addin or a helper script that accepts a "platform" parameter and builds N projects.

Do note the code bellow merely shows how to get what you ask done, but needs to be improved with appropriate *WithCriteria* instructions. If you take it as is, you wont be able to build x64 only.

```
Task("Compile-x86"){ 
    BuildA(); 
    BuildB(); 
    BuildC();
 }; 

 Task("Init-x64")
    .IsDependentOn("Compile-x86"){ 
    //Your init code goes here 
 }; 

 Task("Compile-x64")
    .IsDependentOn("Init-x64"){ 
    BuildA(); 
    BuildB();
    BuildC();
 }; 

 Task("Compile-All-Platforms")
 .IsDependentOn("Compile-x64");
```

Comment: Hello Renaud,
Thank you for your answer. I thought I could minimize the number of tasks and functions. Basically the functions would do the job I need.
I would suggest to improve the documentation because for me it was not clear that C# Make behaves like this until I ran into trouble.

Comment: ...and another important thing should be better highlighted in the documentation for newbies: If you are using "WithCriteria" in a task that has dependencies defined like "IsDependentOn...", the tasks will be executed although the criteria of the dependee is not fulfilled.
Once you know this you can handle it.

Comment: You could probably submit your comments at https://cakebuild.net/, as I am not a Cake contributor.
That being said, if your build steps are complex enough, you could (should?) use Cake extension modules to encapsulate each build step. You could call it twice in a method, and change the configuration between calls. But then you'd have a monolithic build script, although I am pretty sure you are better off with more steps, leveraging the task dependencies.
Do note we dont know the actualy complexity of your system, this answer takes for granted you have 3 projects with 2 targetted platforms.

Comment: I've merged some Tasks, the solution is much simpler now, see if this meets your requirements better